# The math of waiting to be sitted

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

You arrive to your favorite restaurant\bar only to realize that there is no empty table :(

Assuming there are $n$ number of tables, on average a group at a table spends $\bar t$ time and finally that you are far way from the opening or closing time of the establishment<sup>1</sup>, *how long would you have to wait?*

I have given this much thought and ended up convincing myself that if the arrivals do not follow any distribution (are random), the average time one would have to wait is simply ${\bar t}/n$.

---

**Example:**

$15$ tables and $90$ min of dining on average $\Rightarrow 6$ min of waiting

**Question:**

Is it really so or is my intuition mistaken? Is there *more math* to this problem?

---

<sup>1</sup> *No bias on arrivals or departures of groups.*

Comment: Nice intuition. Read about Little's law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law

Comment: @Ethan: I was thinking about that, but how do you apply Little's law in this case? What are $L$, $\lambda$, and $W$ here?

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks about the link and info. It definitely looks a lot like Little's law but I cannot transform his equations to mine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without Little's law:

Assuming people leave when done at random, with one table in the establishment the departure rate would be one departure per $t$ minutes. With $n$ tables, customers would leave at a rate of $n$ per $t$ minutes, so on average you'd wait $t/n$ minutes for the next free table.

With Little's law (essentially the same argument).

> occupancy = throughput rate * service time

Since the occupancy is $n$ and the service time is $t$ the throughput is $n/t$ customers per minute. So you wait on average $t/n$ minutes for the next customer to depart.

Comment: I see, you apply Little's law applied to the tables alone, not to the whole restaurant (whose current occupancy is $n+1$).

Comment: How can this be true? Suppose there's n=1 table and t=45 minutes. Average waiting time is 1/(45 minute)? It's not done dimensionally correct either (units of 1/minute). Intuitively it should be 45/2 wait, since the remaining time is a uniform distribution over [0,45].

Comment: @PBJ $n/t$ isn't the waiting time, it's the throughput, in customers per minute. IWith one table that's $1/45$ customers per minute, so $45$ minutes per customer.  A uniform distribution on $[0,45]$ has mean $22.5$, not $45$. You need a uniform distribution on $[0,90]$ to get a mean of $45$. Moreover, the argument is independent of the distribution as long as you assume steady state.

Comment: Good point on the distribution of waiting time. But your answer says "on average you'd wait n/t minutes for the next free table" - this should actually read (t/n) minutes, right?

Comment: @PBJ You are absolutely correct. I edited my answer; now it's correct. I often get the algebraic version wrong even when I understand it and have the idea right. I suspect the OP understood what I meant and ignored what I wrote when they accepted the answer. Thanks.